# Нужно перевести программу из Pascal в Python. Нужно срочно

Tags: python, pascal

```
program zadanie10; 
var x,y,a: integer; 
begin writeln(‘Введите значения x и y’); 
readln(x,y); 
if x>y then 
begin a:=x;
x:=y;
y:=a;
writeln(‘x=’,x); 
writeln(‘y=’,y); 
end; 
end.
```

""

```
program zadanie12; 
var x, y: integer; 
begin writeln('x = ');
readln(x); 
if x < 0 then 
y := -1 
else 
if x = 0 then 
y := 0 
else 
if x > 0 then 
y := 1; 
writeln ('y = ', y); 
end.
```

Comment: Дайте хоть шнурки догладить

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
print("Введите значения x и y")
x, y = input().split() #ввод сразу 2х значений
a = 0
if x > y:
    a = x
    x = y
    y = a
print("x =",x)
print("y =",y)
```

2я задача:

```
print("Введите значения x ")
x = int(input())
if x < 0:
    y = -1
elif x == 0:
    y = 0
else:
    y = 1

print("y =",y)
```

P.S я эти задачи сделал, потому что было интересно, помню я паскаль или нет